# Detecting jquery-ui accordion open / close state

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How do I conditionally handle when an accordion section is open. What I am asking is this (in pseudo code):

```
if (this-accordion-section-open){
   do something
}
else {
   do something else
}
```

I am looking for something like :isvisible.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

following code return you the active panel,

```
var active = $( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active" );
```

Answer (score 4):

The basic HTML structure of the accordion is:

```
<h3>
    <a>...</a>
</h3>
```

The way I have done it in the past is to assign a class to the  tag like so:

```
<h3>
    <a class="my_accordion">...</a>
</h3>
```

jQuery UI assigns different classes to the  tag based on its state.

```
if($('.my_accordion').parent('h3').hasClass('ui-state-active')) {
    // accordion is open
}
else {
    // accordion is closed
}
```

Answer (score 2):

from the [demo site](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/), I noticed there's a `ui-state-active` class on opened section. So you can use [jQuery.hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) for your code...

Answer (score -2):

Solution for the current clicked link is activate:

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="accordion">

    <div>
        <h2><a href="#services">Services</a></h2>
        <p>More information about all of these services</p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h2><a href="#about">About</a></h2>
        <p>About us</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

**Jquery Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h2", navigation: true });
});
</script>
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your post please include how/why your post will solve the problem.