# Jquery UI Accordion expand/collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I'm using the jQuery UI accordion and attempting to get the expand and collapse all buttons to hide and show when the corresponding button is clicked.

The idea would be that once the expand all button has been clicked and the accordion panels open up then the expand all would be replaced with collapse all and visa versa.

How do I go about switching between the two so only "expand all" or "Collapse all" appear. Instead of both alongside each other?

Thanks.

```
<span class='accordion-expand-all accordion_switch'><a href='#'>Expand all</a></span> 

/ 

<span class='accordion-collapse-all accordion_switch'><a href='#'>Collapse all</a></span>
```

Comment: and your problem is ..... ? to expand and collapse accordion ? or buttons showing and hiding ?

Comment: How do I go about switching between the two so only "expand all" or "Collapse all" appear. Instead of both alongside each other

Comment: You should be using `<button>`s instead of `<a>`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want your links to show and hide then refer to [**Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/MY6A4/1/)

You just have to register the `click` events on your classes and then show and hide according to where click happens.

simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

first set collapsible to true: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-collapsible.
next check for an active panel and use that to show/hide the correct button

```
 var active = $( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active" );
```

found this here: [Detecting jquery-ui accordion open / close state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543591/detecting-jquery-ui-accordion-open-close-state)